# Иконка на потив текста как на скриншоте

Tags: html

[image: Картинка с кодом и результатом]

Добрый день. Не могу понять как автор подвязал изображения к тексту, при этом css не использовался
Ниже прикрепляю код html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i>
                <span> - Facebook</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-x-twitter"></i>
                <span> - Twitter</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-tiktok"></i>
                <span> - TikTok</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
                <span> - Instagram</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body> 
<html>
```

Comment: [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.ru/all-icons/)

Answer (score 4):

Это специальные шрифтовые иконки, в примере это [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/).

Они работают как обычный текст, располагаются при помощи `display: inline`, по этом их можно просто вставиться рядом с текстом без использования CSS.
Их плюс, в отличии от картинок:
* Лучше качество, при разных размерах - потому, что это векторное изображение;
* Возможность стилизации:

```css
a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#"><i class="fab fa-html5"></i> - HTML</a>
```

Из минусов:
- Если использовать фулл билд (со всеми иконками и вариациями, как многие используют) - большой вес и много запросов, следовательно, дольше загрузка;
- [Цена](https://fontawesome.com/plans) (да, это платно) - на данный момент 99$ за год по тарифу **Pro** и 499$ за год по тарифу **Pro Max**

---

Но и картинку можно расположить так же, без использования CSS, потому что по дефолту она тоже `display: inline`:

```css
a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/TAFck96.png" height="16" alt=""> - HTML</a>
```